# TypeScript params for Promise<T>, why not Promise<T1,T2>?

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, typescript2.3

I am wondering why `Promise<T>` doesn't take two params, like so: `Promise<T1,T2>`.

for example:

```
new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
     ...
   err ? reject(err) : resolve(val);
});
```

=>  how can I tell the consumer of the promise about the type of both err **and** val?

I would expect `T1` to be the `Error` type and `T2` to be the type of `val`.

Why doesn't Promise take two type parameters? Because it officially takes only one, I assume the parameter is the type of the value passed to `resolve()`? Is there only one parameter because we expect an `Error` type to always be passed to `reject()`?

In further detail, we can pass a string to reject:

```
  new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       let err = 'just a string, not an object';
       let val = {foo:'bar'};
       err ? reject(err) : resolve(val);
    });
```

Note that we could *coerce the error to a certain type*, like so:

```
return function(){
  return Promise.resolve('whatever')
    .catch(function(){
        return Promise.reject('always a string');
     });
}
```

so it's not really true that the error could always be `any`thing? Seems like we know the error will be a string in the above example...

Comment: reject has type of `(reason? :any) => void` so you can send it anything.

Comment: I think it is because since in Javascript you can throw anything, it is difficult to predict what the error type will be .. but it's just a hunch..

Comment: Also, why an api is built like it is is not really something SO will be able to answer, this is a bit too broad and opinion based.

Comment: @toskv I think the question was more as to why is it `any` and we can't specify an actual type

Comment: I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir And that answer is opinion based

Comment: @toskv ok so reject is already defined somehow, and it must be type `any`? It's a shame we can't change that to be more specific...

Comment: @PabloLozano you are right about that :)

Comment: It would be nice to be able to specify the type of the reject reason. But why it was not made like that by the typescript developers is not something SO is able to help you with.

Comment: Why wouldn't SO be able to help? You have already helped me understand this, and probably other people as well. If you want an upvote add an answer.

Comment: SO doesn't do 'Why' questions the way your title is worded. :) Your last question in the post would make a much better title. How you can specify the reject reason of a promise is something SO can help you.. It's a no you can't answer but still is less ambiguous. :)

Comment: @AlexanderMills in case I was too subtle, my previous answer was urging you to change the title of the post. :D

Comment: I see, hmmmmm, let me try to re-engineer the question

Comment: I added some tulips, maybe it's better now :)

Comment: @toskv I accepted your answer because I think it's reasonable, but I think maybe the TypeScript solution is incomplete.

Comment: Typescript is open source, if you want to change something get on github and make a proposal.

Comment: I do it all the time, I am all up in their github, but let me know if you think I am right

Comment: maybe sometime in the future. Right now, as far as I know, there is no way of making one of the types in a generic declaration optional and you can't define the same interface twice with different parameters. This change would break a LOT of code.

Comment: yeah I guess `Promise<T1,T2?>` doesn't quite exist lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the **reject** parameter is typed as `(reason? : any) => void` you can't specify the type of the reject reason.

As to why it is typed this way, the most likely the main reason is the one @Titian gave. Anything inside the code that throws something would be caught by the promise and propagated up the promise chain as the error. Giving it a type might make the user think it's supposed to expect only a specific type while it could really be **any**thing.

Mainly for situations like this one:

```js
let x = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
  let rnd = Math.random();
  if (rnd < 0.3) {
    resolve('yeey works');
  } else if (rnd < 0.6) {
    reject('boo I dont like this number');
  } else {
    crash();
  }
});

x.then(console.log).catch(console.log);

function crash() {
  throw new DOMException();
}
```

Comment: This is partly true, but for simple promises, we actually do know what the error type is. And you can always add a catch block, and coerce the error to a certain type.